# How to install apache in Raspberry without internet?

Tags: apache, raspberry-pi, apache2, raspberry-pi3, manual

What happens is that I need to create an offline installer of Apache to run it on many Raspberry Pi, I downloaded several apache.tar files from [the official page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/install.html), however I couldn't carry out the installation manually.

For instance, following the steps of the official website I have tried this, step by step:

```
$ gzip -d httpd-NN.tar.gz
$ tar xvf httpd-NN.tar
$ cd httpd-NN
$ ./configure --prefix=PREFIX
$ make
$ make install
$ vi PREFIX/conf/httpd.conf
$ PREFIX/bin/apachectl -k start
```

And the issue is this:

```
checking for chosen layout... Apache
checking for working mkdir -p... yes
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking build system type... armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
checking host system type... armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
checking target system type... armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
configure:
configure: Configuring Apache Portable Runtime library...
configure:
checking for APR... no
configure: error: APR not found.  Please read the documentation.
```

Could someone help for me? Thank you.

Comment: You'd need to add some logs on the errors you're getting and shed some light on why you are unable to carry out the installation.

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/install.html - See requirements at the bottom for APR